# Excel VBA select range at last row and column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a `macro` that selects the range of last row and last column.

E.g. I want to select 1, 2, 3, 4 from my spreadsheet and then delete the selection.

Data:

```
John  | 10 | 10 | 10
Smith | 5  | 5  | 5
Fred  | 8  | 8  | 8 
1     | 2  | 3  | 4
```

Here is my code, it only selects the the last row on the A column. (selects 1 and deletes it). I need it to select 1 to 4 and delete the whole row.

```
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Answer (score 15):

Is this what you are trying? I have commented the code so that you will not have any problem understanding it.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = [Sheet1]

    With ws
        '~~> Get the last row and last column
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        '~~> Set the range
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(lRow, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol))

        With rng
            Debug.Print .Address
            '
            '~~> What ever you want to do with the address
            '
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

BTW I am assuming that `LastRow` is the same for all rows and same goes for the columns. If that is not the case then you will have use `.Find` to find the Last Row and the Last Column. You might want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: I put `Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp` inside the With rng block of code but it doesn't delete the selection

Comment: It won't ;) Try `.Delete Shift:=xlUp` After the debug statement.

Comment: Can you post the exact code that you are using in the question above? I just tested it and it works.

Comment: I copied the exact code into my Module but it only deletes the the A column

Comment: I also tried changing the Set range to `range(Cells(myRow, myCol), Cells(myRow, myCol))`

Comment: May I see your excel file. There is obviously something which you are doing wrong. As I mentioned, I have tested the above code.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest modification (to the code in your question) is this:

```
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way:

```
ActiveSheet.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count+1).Select    
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

or simpler:

```
ActiveSheet.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count+1).EntireRow.Delete
```