# Macro for selecting from multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel

I need help on macros in Excel. I have a table in Excel (example attached).

I need columns A, E and G from source sheet, after last row  i need A,E and H , after last row A,E and I and so on. Means Column A and E will be constant, only third column will change until column K.
In vertical manner.

Source data:

```
A      B     C      D       E       F     G     H        I     J      K
NAME  AGE    CITY  STATE  COUNTRY  CODE  PART  DUEDATE  VEND   COMM   QTY
```

Target:

```
A E G
A E H
A E I
A E J
A E K
```

EDIT: Code I am trying:

```
Sub Mosaic()

With ws
'Get the last row and last column
lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

With ws2
    'Get the last row and last column
    lRow2 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lCol2 = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

'Save the range from A1:Alastrow and E1:Elastrow and store as variable
Set aRng = ws.Range("A1" & lRow)
Set aRng2 = ws.Range("E1" & lRow)
'Union(AE range and G1:Glastrow)

Set gRng = ws.Range("G1" & lRow)
Set hRng = ws.Range("H1" & lRow)

Set uRng = Union(aRng, aRng2, gRng)
uRng.Copy
ws2.Range("A" & lRow2).PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far?  There are many examples of doing this available for easy searching on SO.  SO is not a code outsourcing site...

Comment: Hi,Thanks for advising.I have attached snipped of code i developed from your logic but its not working.

Comment: Hi, I need some more help, there seems to be a modification  in output.Please see the output required at my page

Answer (score 0):

Finding last rows: [Excel VBA select range at last row and column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952362/excel-vba-select-range-at-last-row-and-column)

1. Find the last row of data on source sheet and store as variable.
2. Save the range from A1:Alastrow and E1:Elastrow and store as variable (since we need it three times)
3. Union(AE range and G1:Glastrow)
4. Copy / Paste
5. Union(AE range and H1:Hlastrow)
6. Copy
7. Find destination last row
8. Paste destination last row + 1
9. Repeat for all I, J, and K

You can write your own code from the help file provided

Edit:  The fix for your code:

```
Sub Mosaic()
    Dim aRng, eRng, extraRng as Range
    Dim lRow, lRow2, CurCol as Long

        With ws
        'Get the last row and last column
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        End With

        'Save the range from A1:Alastrow and E1:Elastrow and store as variable
        Set aRng = ws.Range("A1:A" & lRow)
        Set aRng2 = ws.Range("E1:E" & lRow)
    For CurCol = 7 to 11 'Cols G (7) to K (11)
        Set extraRng = ws.Range(Cells(2, CurCol),Cells(lRow, CurCol))
        'Always get the lRow2 right before pasting to ensure you have the last row.
            'Get the last row of destination sheet
            lRow2 = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        aRng.Copy
        ws2.Range("A" & lRow2).PasteSpecial
        eRng.Copy
        ws2.Range("B" & lRow2).PasteSpecial
        extraRng.Copy
        ws2.Range("C" & lRow2).PasteSpecial
    Next CurCol
End Sub
```

Comment: Why comment that a question is a bad fit and then post an answer anyway? If the question is a likely duplicate (as your comment suggests) then please find an appropriate, answered question and flag this one as a duplicate of that question. If the question is not a duplicate but is still just a "gimme teh codez" question that shows no effort then simply downvote and move on, don't justify the question by answering it. Also you've formatted your list as if it was code, I think my VBA editor would throw a fit if I tried to run that lot.

Comment: I see you found the actual list markdown. With regards to answering bad questions it's still bad form to do so, whether you gain rep or not. Answering bad questions indirectly encourages people to _ask_ them by legitimizing their questions and I'm sure you can appreciate that a continuous stream of bad questions is not something StackOverflow needs. You can see a moderator's stance on such questions [on this answer to a Meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277140/3725745).

Comment: Hi,I need one more help.There is a modification in the output.

Comment: Hi, I need one more help,Please see answer below on my page